# CPU simulator with an assembler, linker with Simple assembly

Tags: assembly, cpu, loader, simulator

Do somebody know some CPU simulator featuring simple assembly language
with assembler, loader, linker for learning and testing purpose.
That I could run on GNU systems.

Comment: Rather than some particular Architecture's assembly, It would be really good, if Simulator feature simpler assembly, that one can start using immediately (but I am not sure if MIPS or ARM are featuring that kind of assembly language as their simulator suggested in answers.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try [SPIM](http://pages.cs.wisc.edu/~larus/spim.html).

Comment: I recommend [MARS](http://courses.missouristate.edu/KenVollmar/MARS/) over SPIM for MIPS simulator. It's helpful for MIPS. It also runs on JVM!

Answer (score 1):

I have a thumb (arm 16 bit instruction set). gcc and llvm tools are readily available for C, if you dont need that complication binutils is all you need, easy to cross compile.  codesourcery lite is a gcc based fully functional C++/C toolchain with gnu assembler and linker.

http://github.com/dwelch67/thumbulator/wiki/thumbulator

gcb comes with armulator, less visibility into what is going on.

Answer (score 0):

[apoo](http://freshmeat.net/projects/apoo/)

[An environment for a first course in assembly language programming](http://www.ncc.up.pt/Apoo/)